# gchart not working

Tags: ruby, rubygems, google-visualization

Okay, I want to draw charts within Ruby, so I've found gem called Googlecharts. Here's the problem:

```
-> % irb
1.9.2-p320 :001 > require 'gchart'
  => true 
1.9.2-p320 :002 > Gchart.line(:size => '200x200', :title => 'title', :bg => 'ffffff', :data => [10,20,30,50])
  => "http://chart.apis.google.com/chart?"
```

As you can see, there's no link. What's wrong?

Comment: Are you using [Googlecharts](http://googlecharts.rubyforge.org/) or [gchart](http://rubygems.org/gems/gchart)?

Comment: Can you add your `gem lit` output to your question ?